# Is there a way to switch into another user account from a script?

Tags: login, lightdm, user-management

Let's say I have an account on a small network of machines that is set to auto-login. If one of the machines has a problem with the network or one of its services, I need to break out of the application the default account is running and kill it, which then takes me to the login prompt. Currently this is done with a custom control-alt-delete.conf:

```
description    "Kill flock on control+alt+delete"

start on control-alt-delete

task

exec killall flock_start
```

Is there a way I can add a line to have lightdm automatically log in to the troubleshooting account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this works, if anyone else ever needs to do this:

```
dm-tool switch-to-user [username]
```